# Difference between "no more used" and "no longer used"

Tags: word-choice, differences, adverbs

You can say *not used any more* just as readily as *not used any longer*, but *it is no more used* seems quite wrong compared to *it is no longer used*. Why?

Comment: Though *no more <v; pt>* is found in writing, logic would suggest that *no longer* is more appropriate considering the reference is to time. You could say 'It takes longer to do', but in 'It takes more to do', it could be more time or likely, more effort.

Comment: *No more used* sounds a bit weird to me. Better, but a bit archaic/dated would be *used no more* if we have to stick with those three words. *No longer used* is standard phrasing.

Answer (score 5):

For the sense "not used anymore", one could say "It is used no more".  [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+longer+used%2Cused+no+more%2Cnot+used+any+more%2Cnot+used+anymore%2Cnot+used+any+longer&year_start=1780&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *no longer used,used no more,not used any more,not used anymore,not used any longer* [listed in descending order of frequency and shown in first figure below] shows that usage of *no longer used* has increased substantially in the last 200 years or so.  Looking closer at [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=n-l-u%2Cused+no+more%2Cnot+used+any+more%2Cnot+used+anymore%2Cnot+used+any+longer&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for the latter four terms [as in second figure] shows *used no more* still ahead of the other three; and in the last 15 years, *not used anymore* has overtaken *not used any more*.

Looking at book links from the second ngrams, one will see frequent usage in the 1800's of *no more used*, in just the way that you suggest seems wrong.  Most of the more-recent instances of the phrase in the links are artifactual (*e.g.*: "...if there are no more used memory blocks...").
Part of the problem with "it is no more used" as you have it above is that it may lead one to expect a comparison that is not forthcoming.  Given a comparison, there's no grammatical problem, although phrasing remains clumsy.  Example: "Brand B is no more used than is brand A."

[image: 1780-2008]
[image: 1900-2008]

Comment: +1 for flagging up *used no more*. I'd like to give you another +1 for what look like well-chosen and informative charts!

Comment: _Any more_ (and _any longer, any wider,_ etc, because of the _any_) are [Negative Polarity Items](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) which require a [negative trigger](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) of some sort. In _no more, no longer_, etc. the negative is combined with the NPI quantifier _any_, producing _no_, which has quite different syntax from _not...any_. One can't substitute one phrase for another in just any context.